# What is the history of Gungans and their tech?

Tags: star-wars, technology, the-phantom-menace, races

The Gungans have a dry city underwater, which keeps the water at bay via force fields that block water, but not people entering them.

This struck me as odd, as I wouldn't think they'd evolve to be an underwater species that would need dry/open air living space.

So, where did the Gungans develop as a race/species, and how did they acquire the tech necessary for Gungan City?

Any canon that addresses this question is fine, as I don't expect it to be covered by the current Disney Master Canon.

Comment: Plus they have personal shields that reflect blaster shots and they have crazy electric glob things.

Comment: Humans evolved as arboreal(sp?) species yet you don't spend most of your life in trees, unlike Wookies or Ewoks :)

Comment: @DVK Yeah, but we didn't have to make or acquire new tech to live on the ground, we just did it (and then evolved away features that made tree-climbing feasible)

Comment: @CreationEdge - Sure we did. Haven't you seen 2001? :)

Comment: Plus they live under a seemingly incomprehensibly destructive marine biosphere where whales are eating each other constantly so the audience can be visually entertained. I think this may indicate that a magic intelligence-vacuum-zone exists underwater on Naboo, and that they have no rationally considered history nor evolution.

Comment: @Dronz Good point. The marine life of Naboo is freaking ridiculous. I'm not sure how more than a single breeding pair of some of those giant species could even exist.

Comment: Naboo has no lava/magnetic core. It is water inside through and through. That may allow underwater dinosaurs to exist at mass. As for the Gungans...maybe just want to live on solid ground, but still remain "in the zone"?

Comment: Read somewhere probably in a visual dictionary or something that the Gungans retreated into the water after the Human Naboo started attacking and killing them. This is why they need the force fields to keep the water and monster fish out

Comment: They sprang fully formed from the depths of George Lucas' deranged mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is largely covered in the [Phantom Menace Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_I_The_Visual_Dictionary).

In short, the Gungans evolved in the Naboo swamps, where most of them currently reside. After their planet was contacted and colonised by the Naboobian humans, the Gungans began to trade plasma, food and various manufactured products with the Naboo. This "borrowed tech", along with their own R&D (mostly focusing on on 'grown' technology like their Bongo Submarines and Hydrostatic Bubbles) have allowed them to move large segments of their civilisation underwater.

> *GUNGANS EVOLVED in the swamps of Naboo, becoming almost equally well
>   adapted to life on land and in water. The amphibious beings live in
>   underwater cities hidden in deep lakes, breathing air or water with
>   their compound lungs. Secret techniques allow Gungans to 'grow' the
>   basic structures of buildings and vehicles, which are complemented and
>   finished by Gungan artisans in organic styles. Gungans trade with the
>   Naboo for certain items of technology, but manufacture everything else
>   they need from the resources of their underwater habitat. Although
>   Gungans use mechanized vehicles, they have a close affinity with the
>   natural world and still prefer to utilize living mounts and beasts of
>   burden.*